# Convert from string to us-ascii in c#

Tags: c#, encoding, ascii

I wanto to convert the string like "123" to string like "\u0031\u0032\u0033".
How can i do this in .NET?
For example: reverse convert:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("us-ascii",
                                          new EncoderExceptionFallback(),
                                          new DecoderExceptionFallback());
            byte[] by = enc.GetBytes(s);
            string ans = enc.GetString(by);
            return ans;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings in .NET already are Unicode, so there's no need to convert them from Unicode to Unicode.

If you want to output a unicode escaped string, then try this:

```
string ans = string.Concat(s.Select(c => string.Format("\\u{0:x4}", (int)c)).ToArray());
```

Result:

```
\u0031\u0032\u0033
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/kjwaH)

In .NET 4.0 you can omit the call to `ToArray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string ans = Regex.Replace(s, ".", m => String.Format(@"\u{0:x4}", (int)m.Value[0]));
```